# Answering rspec to raise_error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

Basically I'm trying to answer a series of Rspec instructions. One of those instructions is this:

```
it "fails informatively when there's not enough values stacked away" do
  expect {
     calculator.plus
  }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")
end
```

So I learned about raise_error and how to answer it, it was me to create some sort of error/exception.

```
def plus
  @array_nums.length >= 2 ? @array_nums << @array_nums.pop + @array_nums.pop : raise {"calculator is empty"}
  @value = @array_nums[-1]
```

To be clear there is an end on the bottom but the text editor wasn't processing it. So I'm raising the error, I've tried to raise ArgumentError and all that, but I keep getting this response from the rspec:

```
Failure/Error:
   expect {
     calculator.plus
   }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")

   expected Exception with "calculator is empty", got RuntimeError with backtrace:
     # ./lib/12_rpn_calculator.rb:16:in `plus'
     # ./spec/12_rpn_calculator_spec.rb:119:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/12_rpn_calculator_spec.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/12_rpn_calculator_spec.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any other raised errors I try just don't work, and I'm struggling to find the right direction to take this. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
  @array_nums.length >= 2 ? @array_nums << @array_nums.pop + @array_nums.pop : raise StandardError, 'calculator is empty'
```

Comment: Tried this: This is the error I get - `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in \`load': /home/ubuntu/workspace/test-first-ruby-master/lib/12_rpn_calculator.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
..._nums.pop : raise StandardError, 'calculator is empty`

Comment: Also this is included `/home/ubuntu/workspace/test-first-ruby-master/lib/12_rpn_calculator.rb:16: dynamic constant assignment
...nums.pop : raise StandardError, 'calculator is empty'`

Comment: maybe it's because the ternary, try wrapping raise params in parens

Comment: By the way thank you so much for your help. Still the same error except with the parenthesis I only get the first error and not the second one.

Comment: @BrandonThaler A Ruby error message usually tells you the exact location at which the error occurred (in this case in file `12_rpn_cal‌​culator.rb` at line `16`). Nobody will be able to help you with this without knowledge how that file looks like - especially around line 16.

Comment: @spickermann The code I put above is line 16, would you like me to put the whole code? The rest is just similar functions (instead of add its subtract, divide, multiply) inside a class definition.

Comment: @mr_sudaca Just a suggestion, your answer could be much improved by added reasons why your code works and OPs doesn't. If you do that, you have my +1.