# Keep getting errors using Raise trying to answer Rspec's to raise_error in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec, raiserror

Basically I'm trying to answer a series of Rspec instructions. One of those instructions is this:

```
it "fails informatively when there's not enough values stacked away" do
  expect {
     calculator.plus
  }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")
end
```

So I learned about raise_error and how to answer it, it was me to create some sort of error/exception.

```
def plus
  @array_nums.length >= 2 ? @array_nums << @array_nums.pop + @array_nums.pop : raise {"calculator is empty"}
  @value = @array_nums[-1]
```

To be clear there is an end on the bottom but the text editor wasn't processing it. So I'm raising the error, I've tried to raise ArgumentError and all that, but I keep getting this response from the rspec:

```
Failure/Error:
   expect {
     calculator.plus
   }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")

   expected Exception with "calculator is empty", got RuntimeError with backtrace:
     # ./lib/12_rpn_calculator.rb:16:in `plus'
     # ./spec/12_rpn_calculator_spec.rb:119:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/12_rpn_calculator_spec.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/12_rpn_calculator_spec.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any other raised errors I try just don't work, and I'm struggling to find the right direction to take this. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?

Sorry to ask this question again, but I've tried everything and don't want to have any errors. If you want to check the comments of the other thread [here is the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535312/answering-rspec-to-raise-error-in-ruby/40535427?noredirect=1#comment68312998_40535427).

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is that [`Kernel#raise`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) does not accept a block (`{...}`) as parameters. It accepts an exception or a string.

The next problem you are facing are missing parentheses. While you can omit parentheses in many case, you cannot do that all the time. The reason are different [operator precedences](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence). Operator precedence may confuse developers and lead Ruby to read the code in unexpected ways. For example:

```
condition ? operation : raise "calculator is empty"

# what the devs thinks Ruby would understand:
condition ? operation : raise("calculator is empty")

# what Ruby really understands:
(condition ? operation : raise) "calculator is empty"
```

In fact - most known style guides suggest to not omit parentheses in most case and allow to omit as an exception in some.

Furthermore it feels to me like you try to do to much in just one one: There is the ternary, two `pop` calls, a assignment and a `raise`. That makes the code hard to read, hard to understand and error prone. In this particular example I would suggest to use a guard clause at the beginning of the method and remove the ternary at all:

```
def plus
  raise(ArgumentError, 'calculator is empty') if @numbers.length < 3

  @numbers << @numbers.pop + @numbers.pop
  # ...
```

You will notice that I also explicitly tell the kind of [exception](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html): `ArgumentError` seems to describe the issue best. And I would name the variables differently.

Each language that its own style, best practices, naming conventions and idioms. It is worth it to understand and follow these conventions. You might want to have a look into a well known Ruby style guides like:

- https://github.com/styleguide/ruby
- https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 1):

change `raise {"calculator is empty"}` to `raise("calculator is empty")`. `raise` can take a string argument and not a block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no go. What's weird is the only time the code will actually run is if the string is in the block. I should also maybe mention I'm doing this all in c9's IDE. When I ran it your way I this is the error I got `rspec spec/12_rpn_calculator_spec.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in \`load': /home/ubuntu/workspace/test-first-ruby-master/lib/12_rpn_calculator.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
...pop + @array_nums.pop : raise "calculator is empty"`

Comment: looks like it needed explicit parenthesis when inside of the ternary operator, edited answer to add them.

Comment: Same error, maybe it has something to do with the IDE? Anyway, thanks so much for your help, I just decided to change the raise_error code in the rspec to use RunTimeError as a argument instead of a string, and it works now. Probably not the right solution, but for now it'll have to do.

Comment: that is absolutely the wrong solution. In ruby syntax errors are runtime exceptions, so your just changing your expectations to expect a runtime error, which is just your syntax error